# Can it be fixed?

Tags: boot, screen, plymouth

I just bought a computer that had this operating system on it. I've never even heard if it. I updated​ from 14 something?( I really don't know anything) to the 16.04.2 (that's what it said) my computer froze so I turned it off and when I went to turn it on it got stuck on this screen is there anything that I can do to fix it!??!

This is where i go to everytime I turn my computer on
[image: This is where i go to everytime I turn my computer on]

Comment: Possibly, but if you've never heard of Ubuntu before, the learning curve might be a bit steep. A fix might involve reinstalling the OS, for example.

Comment: You really want to reinstall the OS. Who knows what the previous owner may have done to it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the boot files got corrupt somehow. Your best bet would be to re-install ubuntu. It might be a little new thing to you to install ubuntu if you have never heard of it; but it is not difficult. You just have to remember these values;

/boot =500 MB
swap area = half the size of your total ram
/ = Remaining storage of your computer.

Format all under ext4 partition except swap.

Or if you are still not confident, watch some youtube videos on how to install ubuntu or how to dualboot ubuntu. You will find plenty there.

If you are new to ubuntu; though it is somewhat new to you, you will easily get over it in the matter of days. Youtube's your best bet... and if you have specific problem, we are always here to help...

Comment: Separate boot partitions are neither required not necessarily recommended.